# If $\| \psi \|_2=1$ can I say something about $\| \psi' \|_2$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces

If I have a differentiable $L^2$ function $\psi:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb C$ which is normalised
$$
\int |\psi(x)|^2\;\text d x = 1
$$
can I say anything about the order of
$$
\int |\psi'(x)|^2\;\text d x\quad \text ?
$$

I don't want to keep it as general as possible. More the other way round: What shall I assume to be able to say something? For example we can assume that $|\psi|$ has its single maximum at $x=0$ and then decays rapidly. Furthermore we can say that $\psi$ is an hermitian function.

I made an example with a gaussian with a simple phase
$$
\psi(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{1/4}}\text e^{-\frac{x^2}{4\sigma^2}}\text e^{\text i \omega x}
$$
wich is normalised and found
$$
\int |\psi'(x)|^2\;\text d x = \frac{1}{4\sigma^2}+\omega^2
$$
I guess in the most cases a term proportional to $1/\text{variance}$ will appear. And in the case of a simple phase another term will just be proportional to the frequency squared $\omega^2$.

Comment: By Plancherel and the bahaviour of the derivative under the Fourier Transform , you have (under suitable assumptions) $\Vert \psi' \Vert_2 = \Vert \widehat{\psi'} \Vert_2 = \Vert x \cdot \widehat{\psi}(x) \Vert_2$ and $\Vert \psi \Vert_2 = \Vert \widehat{\psi} \Vert_2$. So your question reduces (without further assumptions on $\psi$) to the question of what ca be said about $\Vert x \cdot \gamma(x) \Vert_2$ assuming that you know $\Vert \gamma \Vert_2$. You should convince yourself that not much can be said here. You can now try to express additional assumptions in terms of $\widehat{\psi}$.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that is differentiable does not mean its derivative is square integrable, for that you need that $\psi\in H^1(\mathbb{R})\subset L^2(\mathbb{R})$, the Sobolev space. Hence you may have any order of magnitude (even infinite) for the $L^2$-norm of the derivative, given a generic differentiable $L^2$ function.